# Intellisense for <tr> and <td>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hey, This is the one i used. For some condition, i want to hide these  by using Visible to false.

```
<tr id="trpackage" runat="server" valign="top" align="center">
<td id="tdpack" runat="server" style="display: none;" align="center">
.......
</td>
</tr>
```

In the code behind, Intellisense does not show me either trpackage or tdpack. Can someone help me !! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Is there a problem with VS 2005 on Intellisense??

Answer (score 0):

Table elements with `runat="server"` tend to become `HtmlTable` or related elements and indeed rows and cells will not appear as properties. If you want to avoid all that hassle, put a `PlaceHolder` around your elements and use that to hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Putting runat="server" on an html element makes it mapped to the type **HtmlGenericControl** if there are no specified HTML controls for it [available](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_htmltablerow.asp). You should be able to type in

```
trpackage.
```

and then Intellisense would kick in. If you type `trpack` and then the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> then Intellisense already kicks in directly for that element as well.

It should work from at least Visual Studio 2008 and higher. I don't have VS2005 on this machine so I couldn't test for that.